# change color of table cell using jsp

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

i have a jsp file which prints a mysql table with the help of jdbc.The columns of table are id, name , division and age.I want to change the color of table cell with age data to change red and green depending upon some particular values.

```
<body>
<%!Connection con; %>
<%!Statement s; %>
<% ResultSet rs=null;
String name=request.getParameter("t1");
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/****","root","****");
s=con.createStatement();
System.out.println(name);
rs=s.executeQuery("select * from employee");
}catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
%>
<div id="dt_table">
<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>Empolyee ID</th>
<th>Empolyee Name</th>
<th>Employee Division</th>
<th>age</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<% try 
{
while(rs.next())
{ %>
<tr>
<td><%=rs.getInt(1)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td> 
<td><%=rs.getInt(4)%></td>
</tr>
<% } 
}catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }%>

</table></div>
</body>
```

This question has been already asked but it has not been answered.Here's the link.
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131874/change-color-of-table-based-on-values-of-mysql-database-using-jsp

I even found something like this in php, but i donot know php,
    [Change color of table based on values from SQL Query database using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014804/change-color-of-table-based-on-values-from-sql-query-database-using-php)

So any help in jsp or javascript may be helpful.Thanks.

Comment: it's not working , and how does it check, which column value it is referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, suppose the fourth column is the age in table:

```
while(rs.next()) {
{ %>
<tr>
<td><%=rs.getInt(1)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getInt(2)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getInt(3)%></td>
<td <%=(rs.getInt(1) > 10 : "style='background-color:red;'" : "")%> ><%=rs.getInt(1)%></td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

Or you simply use If-else if you want.
Hope, it helps!!

Comment: Use style='bg-color:red;' instead of style='background-color:red;'

Answer (score 1):

You could do this based on the header of the table

```
function colorIt() {
  var val = 0; //value to be compared with
  var val2 = 10; //value to be compared with
  var ColIndexToCheck = 0;
  var header = document.getElementById("dt_table").getElementsByTagName("th");
  for (var j = 0; j < header.length; j++) {
    if (header[j].innerHTML == "Age") {
       ColIndexToCheck = j;
     }
}

var trs = document.getElementById("dt_table").getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
    if (trs[i].cells[ColIndexToCheck].innerHTML > val) {
        trs[i].cells[ColIndexToCheck].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    if (trs[i].cells[ColIndexToCheck].innerHTML > val2) {
        trs[i].cells[ColIndexToCheck].style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
}
```

}